# Syntax for Extending AngularJS Route Provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hopefully this question doesn't get erroneously marked as a duplicate.

I am attempting to extend the AngularJS `$routeProvider`, as suggested as a response to a previous question. Unfortunately, this is not working, and I may have the syntax incorrect.

Here is a sanitized version of my "top-level" module:

```
// app.js
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'
        , 'main'
    ])

    .provider('appRoute', ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

        this.$get = function($http) {
            console.log("Instantiaing $rmaRouteProvider");
            var universalResolves = {authorize: function($http) {
                    return $http.get('/svc/authorize/view?urlPath=' + path)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            var data = response.data;
                            if (response.data.result === 'NOT_AUTHORIZED') {
                                throw "NOT_AUTHORIZED";
                            }

                            console.log("finished authorized()");
                            return data;
                        });
                }
            };

            var rmaRouteProvider = angular.extend({}, $routeProvider, {
                when: function(path, route) {
                    route.resolve = (route.resolve) ? route.resolve : {};
                    angular.extend(route.resolve, universalResolves);
                    $routeProvider.when(path, route);
                    return this;
                }
            });

            return rmaRouteProvider;
        }
    }]);
```

Here is my main.js, where I am attempting to define routes using the `appRoute` provider instead of the `$routeProvider`:

```
angular.module('admin', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngCsv'])
.config(['appRouteProvider', function(appRouteProvider) {
       appRouteProvider.when('/route', {

            templateUrl: 'pageTemplate.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'pageCtrl'

       }
]);
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module main due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: appRouteProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24appRouteProvider
minErr/<@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:68:12
createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4511:19
getService@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4664:39
injectionArgs@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4688:58
invoke@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4710:18
runInvokeQueue@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4611:11
loadModules/<@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4620:11
forEach@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:321:11
loadModules@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4601:5
loadModules/<@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4618:40
forEach@http…
```

As I said, I'm hoping this is an error with my syntax.

Edit: I realize that instatiation of providers is load-order specific. The app.js is the first `<script>` imported in the application index.html file and should be loaded first.

Edit 2: I have updated this question to the following: [Custom Route Provider when is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384087/custom-route-provider-when-is-not-a-function)

Comment: You're implementing the `appRouteProvider` within the `module('app')` but you aren't including that module in your `module('admin')` dependencies.  I think...  Maybe put `appRouteProvider` in a separate module, which can be included in both app and admin?

Comment: I've posted an updated question that supercedes this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384087/custom-route-provider-when-is-not-a-function