# Custom Route Provider when is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is an updated version of a question from this morning.

I have two separate modules, 'admin' and 'authorization'. In the provider block of authorization, I extend `$routeProvider` in order to attach an identical route to all of the route definitions.

First, here is admin.js:

```
angular.module('authorization', [])
    .provider('$appRoute', function () {
        this.$get = function($routeProvider) {
            var universalResolves = {authorize: function($authorization) {
                    return $authorization.authorize();
                }};

            var extendedRouter = angular.extend({}, $routeProvider, {
                when: function(path, route) {
                    route.resolve = (route.resolve) ? route.resolve : {};
                    angular.extend(route.resolve, universalResolves);
                    $routeProvider.when(path, route);
                    return this;
                }
            });

            return new extendedRouter();
        }
    })
    .factory('$authorization', ['$http', '$location', function($http, $location) {

        var $authorization = {};

        $authorization.authorize = function() {

            var path = $location.path();

            return promise = $http.get('/svc/authorize/view?urlPath=' + path).then(function(response) {
                var data = response.data;
                if (response.data.result === 'NOT_AUTHORIZED') {
                    throw "NOT_AUTHORIZED";
                }

                return data;
            });

        };

        return $authorization;
    }]);
```

Next, my admin module:

```
angular.module('admin', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngCsv'
        , 'authorization'
    ])

    .controller('mainCtrl', function() {

    })
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$appRouteProvider', function($routeProvider, $appRouteProvider) {

        // old definition that needs to be changed to $appRouteProvider
        $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: '/login/auth.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        });

        $appRouteProvider.when('/page', {
            templateUrl: 'page.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'pageCtrl'
        });
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
$appRouteProvider.when is not a function
@https://localhost:8443/admin.js:87:9
invoke@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4718:16
runInvokeQueue@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4611:11
loadModules/<@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4620:11
forEach@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:321:11
loadModules@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4601:5
loadModules/<@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4618:40
forEach@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:321:11
loadModules@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4601:5
createInjector@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:4523:19
doBootstrap@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:1758:20
bootstrap@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:1779:12
angularInit@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:1664:5
@https://localhost:8443/js/angular/angular.js:31763:5
j@https://localhost:8443/js/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:29566
g/</k<@https://localhost:8443/js/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:29882
```

So it sees the $appRouteProvider, but only the `this.$get()` method. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Just regarding the error, the `$appRoute` provider is not exposing any methods on  it self (other then `$get`). So its an empty api config provider object.

When using the base provider recipe, the `$get` method is used to provide a function to generate the service, and the `this` from the `provider` is used to bind extra config functions to put data the `$get` function can later use.

From [Angular provider docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe):

```
myApp.provider('unicornLauncher', function UnicornLauncherProvider() {
  var useTinfoilShielding = false;

  // provider config api method.
  this.useTinfoilShielding = function(value) {
    useTinfoilShielding = !!value;
  };

  this.$get = ["apiToken", function unicornLauncherFactory(apiToken) {

    // let's assume that the UnicornLauncher constructor was also changed to
    // accept and use the useTinfoilShielding argument
    return new UnicornLauncher(apiToken, useTinfoilShielding);
  }];
});
```

If you want to add additional methods on the provider, you can use `this.when = ...` or `Angular.extends(this, ....)` for instance.

Comment: But am I not already doing this in the angular.extend() method where I create the where() function?

Comment: From what I see, the code is doing `angular.extends({}, ...`, which means you extends an empty object. I think you are looking to do `angular.extends(this, ...)` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Comment: But I'm extending an empty object with the contents of `$routeProvider`, then with the contents of the object where I'm defining when for my new object. That link specifically states that if you want to preserve the original object, you can do so by passing an empty object as the target.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. In the `config` there is a use of ` $appRouteProvider.when`. The `$appRouteProvider` is the `this` that we got earlier in the `provider(`$appRoute'...)`. You have to put the methods on the `this` or no methods will be exposed. Doing `angular.extends({}..) and returning the result in the $get does not achieve this target.

Comment: You're still only extending within the get method. That's too late. As the answer states it's got to be done in the main function isung this as the base object.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with a simpler solution than extending the route provider.

In my "top-level" module, I modified all routes with the following code:

```
angular.module('app'[])
    .run(function($route) {
        var keys = Object.keys($route.routes);
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
            var modifiedRoute = $route.routes[key];

            // if there's already a resolve function defined, don't overwrite it, just add a new one
            modifiedRoute.resolve = key.resolve?key.resolve:{};
            modifiedRoute.resolve.authorize = function($authorization) {
                return $authorization.authorize();
            }

            $route[key] = modifiedRoute;
        });
     });
```

This works because the routes were already defined in the other modules `.config()` blocks, which executed before the `run()` block. It's slightly ugly, but it works.